Do tire chains fit on 2010 Silverado 1500?
Do snow chains fit on a 2010 Silverado 1500 4WD? Winter tire size is 265/70R17.
Or will the chains hit other parts of the truck causing damage?

According to the manual, no.

From a quick glance, there doesn't seem to be much room between the front tire and the fender wall. This ruler is 7/8 of an inch wide, and it only fits if squished between the tire and the fender wall. So the gap is a bit smaller.
Front left:


So I would be worried the chain would hit the fender wall, especially with chains that have V-bars like these:

Light Truck Lightweight Canadian Spec V-Bar Tire Chain
Edit: Maybe a better answer is: No, they don’t fit on the front wheels.

Quite a good answer, with documentation, photos of measurements, etc.

That is a surprisingly (no, stunningly) low amount of clearance for a 4WD vehicle - won't take much mud to really make a mess there.

@JonCuster I wonder if the stock tires were a different size.

@User1974 - good point, but clearly the 70R17 were considered likely enough to include in the manual. My truck manual doesn't say anything about any other tire size than what is fitted, even though larger tires (a common upgrade) would fit with more clearance than you have there.
